# Definition of a regular surface

Tags: differential-geometry, surfaces

Here is the definition of a regular surface from Differential Geometry of Curves and Surfaces by Manfredo do Carmo:

> A subset $S ⊂ \mathbb R^3$ is a regular surface if, for each $p ∈ S$, there exists a neighborhood $V ⊂ \mathbb R^3$ and a map $f : U → V ∩ S$ of an open set $U ⊂ \mathbb R^2$ onto $V ∩ S ⊂ \mathbb R^3$ such that
>
> - $f$ is $C^\infty$.
> - $f$ is a homeomorphism. Since $f$ is continuous, this means that $f$ has an inverse $f^{-1} : V ∩ S → U$ which is continuous; that is, $f^{-1}$ is the restriction of a continuous map $F : W ⊂ \mathbb R^3 → \mathbb R^2$ defined on an open set $W$ containing $V ∩ S$.
> - For each $q ∈ U$ holds $f'(q) : \mathbb R^2 → \mathbb R^3$ is one-to-one.

I don't understand what is meant by

> that is, $f^{-1}$ is the restriction of a continuous map $F : W ⊂ \mathbb R^3 → \mathbb R^2$ defined on an open set $W$ containing $V ∩ S$

Why does it mention $W ⊂ \mathbb R^3$ and the restriction?

Comment: this refers to the induced topology on $S$: a set $X$ in $S$ is called open, if there exists some open $A \subset \mathbb{R}^3$ such that $X = S \cap A$. equivalently he uses that concept for homeomorphisms. I would say if you have enough background it's not necessary to state that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

He mentions that to specify what he means by continuity of $f^{-1}$, probably for those readers who don't have any background in topology. In general a map is called continuous if preimages of open sets are open. Therefore you need to know which sets are called open - i.e. the topology, in this case the induced topology of $S$. His way to avoid this is saying that $f^{-1}$ is the restriction of some "bigger" map and therefore he creates $W$.

However, if you have some basic topology knowledge you can skip that. Its enough to say $S$ is locally homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^2$. (where $X \subset S$ is called open, if $X = A \cap S$ for some open $A \subset \mathbb{R}^3$)